# Ternary Plot Heat Map Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap, ternary-representation

I have 4 columns of data: a:b:c:t 
I want a b c to be the coordinates on my ternary plot and then the corresponding t column would provide the 'heat level' of each point. So far I have the code to produce regular ternary plots and my data is in a .txt file and is of the form:

```
a1 b1 c1 t1 
a2 b2 c2 t2 
a3 b3 c3 t2
etc
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The basic syntax is

```
splot 'datafile' using 1:2:3:4 with points lc palette
```